# default-view-inclusion not working

Tags: java, json, spring

Hello everyone I've been looking through posts related to this problem but I didn't succeed to solve it. Actually I'm using spring boot 1.6 with jackson and others APIs. When I use @JsonView on an attribut, It is included in the final Json produced with Advanced Rest Client. however attributs with no @JsonView are not included in the serialization. I found that "spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion" is "true" by default I tried to follow this link http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews, but it does not work. My main concern is to create view without having to use @JsonView on attribut that are included in all views, so just use @Json view for attributs that depends on views but it does not work. this is one of my entity

```
public class Person  implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1151758997545437061L;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @JsonView(UserViews.SimpleView.class)
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birthDate;

    @JsonView(UserViews.SimpleView.class)
    private String birthPlace;

// getters and setters
}
```

and here is my controller

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public class PersonController {


        private Logger logger= org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonController.class);

        @Autowired
        private PersonService<Person, PersonDao<Person>> personService;

        public PersonService<Person, PersonDao<Person>> getPersonService() {
            return personService;
        }

        public void setPersonService(PersonService<Person, PersonDao<Person>> personService) {
            this.personService = personService;
        }

        //-------------------Retrieve All Person--------------------------------------------------------
        @GetMapping(value = "/person")
    @JsonView(UserViews.SimpleView.class)
        public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> findAllPerson() throws Exception {
            logger.error("##############################Loading person################################");
            List<Person> listPersons = personService.findAll();
            if (listPersons.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(listPersons, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        //-------------------Retrieve filtered list Person--------------------------------------------------------
        @PostMapping(value = "/person/filtered")
    @JsonView(UserViews.RoleView.class)
        public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> findFilterperson() throws Exception {
            List<Person> listPersons = personService.findAll();
            if (listPersons.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(listPersons, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

I even add this to my application.properties

```
spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion:true
```

I was expecting to have firstName and LastName in all my view but I didn't get those two fields

Comment: If you have at least one annotation, all the non-annotated attributes are not included anymore as per [doc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION). Do you have any?

Comment: yes I do have annotations

Comment: Have you tried without?

Comment: `default-view-inclusion` works for me only when it enabled through java code